How do catholics explain hereditary diseases?
The short list of hereditary diseases includes color blindness, down syndrome, hemophilia, sickle cell disease, and albinism.
The short list of sexually transmitted diseases includes chancroid, chlamydia, gonorrhea, herpes, HIV/AIDS, human papillomavirus/genital warts and syphilis.
All of these diseases require that another person has previously had them, either your parents or your sexual partner.
Humanity begins with Adam and Eve, who must have carried all of these diseases to pass them on to their offspring.
Did God created Adam and Eve loaded with all those diseases?
How do catholics explain this situation?

You have included, in your argument, the crucial effects of the old, antediluvian, world and the global effects of the Flood in the days of Noah and the continuing judgments of God upon the earth, specifically designed to curb, judge and limit humankind.

"All of these diseases require that another person has previously had them, either your parents or your sexual partner." If this sentence is true (it isn't), then it is impossible for anyone, theist or atheist, to answer the question, unless we posit that the human race has always been. No one today believes this.

How do catholics explain hereditary diseases?
In the beginning, God created man and woman. But when Adam and Eve sinned, God cursed them and their ospring. This was one of the physical conditions imposed on mankind because of the first sin of our original parents. Thus original sin can into the world.
With baptism, the stain of original sin is cleansed from our souls, but our physical nature remains damaged through original sin. Thus decease and death remained our lot. Remember well that Eve was told she would bare children in pain. Baptism does not take away the pain of child bearing from women. “To the woman also he said: I will multiply thy sorrows, and thy conceptions: in sorrow shalt thou bring forth children, and thou shalt be under thy husband's power, and he shall have dominion over thee.” - (Genesis 3:16).
Mankind thus will live knowing pain, disease suffering and yes the possibility of hereditary diseases, etc. will be the natural course of things for mankind. Baptism restores us to friendship with God but our human nature remains damaged to some degree.

Original sin (peccatum originale) in Christian theology refers to the condition of sinfulness that all humans share, which is inherited from Adam and Eve due to the Fall, involving the loss of original righteousness and the distortion of the Image of God. The biblical basis for the belief is generally found in Genesis 3 (the story of the expulsion of Adam and Eve from the Garden of Eden), and in texts such as Psalm 51:5 ("I was brought forth in iniquity, and in sin did my mother conceive me") and Romans 5:12–21 ("Therefore, just as sin entered the world through one man, and death through sin, and in this way death came to all people, because all sinned").
The specific doctrine of original sin was developed in the 3rd century struggle against Gnosticism by Irenaeus of Lyons, and was shaped significantly by Augustine of Hippo (354–430 AD), who was the first author to use the phrase "original sin". Influenced by Augustine, the Councils of Carthage (411–418 AD) and Orange (529 AD) brought theological speculation about original sin into the official lexicon of the Church.
Roman Catholicism
In the theology of the Roman Catholic Church, original sin is the absence of original holiness and justice into which humans are born, distinct from the actual sins that a person commits. The absence of sanctifying grace or holiness in the new-born child is an effect of the first sin, for Adam, having received holiness and justice from God, lost it not only for himself but also for humanity. The Catechism of the Catholic Church sets forth the Roman Catholic doctrine of original sin in brief.

By his sin Adam, as the first man, lost the original holiness he had received from God, not only for himself but for all humans.

Adam and Eve transmitted to their descendants human nature wounded by their own first sin and hence deprived of original holiness and justice; this deprivation is called "original sin".

As a result of original sin, human nature is weakened in its powers, subject to ignorance, suffering and the domination of death, and inclined to sin (this inclination is called "concupiscence").


Anselm of Canterbury wrote that "there is a difference between the sin of Adam on the one hand, and the sins of children on the other: one is the cause and one is the effect." Following this, Roman Catholic doctrine sees the original sin of a child as distinct from the fault of Adam, but rather as one of its effects. The effects of Adam's sin according to the Catholic Encyclopedia are the following.

Death and suffering: "One man has transmitted to the whole human race not only the death of the body, which is the punishment of sin, but even sin itself, which is the death of the soul."

Concupiscence or inclination to sin: baptism erases original sin but the inclination to sin remains.

The absence of sanctifying grace in the new-born child is also an effect of the first sin, for Adam, having received holiness and justice from God, lost it not only for himself but also for humanity. Baptism confers original sanctifying grace, lost through the Adam's sin, thus eliminating original sin and any personal sin.


The Roman Catholic Church teaches that every human person born on earth is made in the image of God. Within man "is both the powerful surge toward the good because we are made in the image of God, and the darker impulses toward evil because of the effects of Original Sin". Furthermore, it explicitly denies that guilt is inherited from anyone, maintaining that instead humanity inherits its own fallen nature. In this it differs from the Reformed position that each person actually inherits Adam's guilt, and teaches instead that "original sin does not have the character of a personal fault in any of Adam's descendants [...] but the consequences for nature, weakened and inclined to evil, persist in man". This view, that human beings do not bear guilt for the sin of Adam, is also held in Eastern Orthodoxy. The Roman Catholic Church teaches, "By our first parents' sin, the devil has acquired a certain domination over man, even though man remains free."

Original Sin



Viruses and bacteria evolve over time; so I think this question would pose the most trouble for fundamentalists who deny evolution occurs. In 1950, Pope Pious XII confirmed that there is no conflict between belief in Christianity and the Theory of Evolution. See here:

In the 1950 encyclical Humani generis, Pope Pius XII confirmed that there is no intrinsic conflict between Christianity and the theory of evolution, provided that Christians believe that God created all things and that the individual soul is a direct creation by God and not the product of purely material forces.

Now, depending upon how literal an individual takes Genesis to be, they may have trouble accounting for the time needed for such diseases to evolve. However, even a literal interpretation of Genesis has good internal evidence that the "days" in Genesis 1 are not be understood as our 24 hour cycles that we know. In particular, a "day" is defined to be the "light" from the first day of creation (Genesis 1:5) - but it isn't until the fourth such "day" that the sun, moon, and stars are created (Genesis 1:14-19).
Also, there is nothing stopping a fundamentalist from saying that such diseases were introduced as punishments by God after the fall.

"they may have trouble accounting for the time needed for such diseases to evolve" — It can happen in a very short time. E.g. many flu epidemics are caused by recombined DNA at farms in China where ducks and swine are raised together. These genetic changes can happen at any time, almost instantly, and certainly don't require thousands or millions of years.
